# Set the zoom size of the excel using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, excel

i want to set the zoom size in the excel to 75% programmatic before it gets downloaded. The default value is set to 100% by default. Can any one help me out to solve this?

I use the below code to get the data from reports and store it in a byte array

```
 bytes = rptViewer.ServerReport.Render("EXCELOPENXML", deviceInfo,
                    out mimeType, out encoding, out extensions, out streamids, out warnings);
```

Then passing the information to the below method to download the file in excel

```
private HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(string mimeType, byte[] bytes, string rptName, string extensions)
    {
        string fileName = rptName + "." + extensions;
        HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
            response.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return response;
        }
        return msg.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "File not found.");
    }
```

so when it get download, it is set to be 100% by default. i want to it to be 75% by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a way to access the Excel.Application. Then this should be enough:

```
Application.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
```

---

In general, this code opens a workbook and sets each worksheet to `10` zoom. You can use it as a reference:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

class LooperMain
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        excel.Visible = true;
        string strReportName = @"C:\somePath\123.xlsx";
        Excel.Workbook wkb =  Open(excel, strReportName);
        SetZoom(10, wkb, excel);
    }

    public static void SetZoom(int zoomLevel, 
                              Excel.Workbook wb, 
                              Excel.Application excelInstance)
    {
        foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
        {
            ws.Activate();
            excelInstance.ActiveWindow.Zoom = zoomLevel;
        }
    }

    public static Excel.Workbook Open(Excel.Application excelInstance, 
                               string fileName, bool readOnly = false, 
                               bool editable = true, bool updateLinks = true)
    {
        Excel.Workbook book = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(
            fileName, updateLinks, readOnly);                                  
        return book;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SSRS or Report Viewer doesn't provide a way to customize the zoom level of exported excel file. 
You might need to save the bytes into a file, open it programatically with excel manipulation libraries like [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki), change the zoom level and write the file back to the response.

```
File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.xlsx", bytes);
var wb = new XLWorkbook("Foo.xlsx");
var ws = wb.Worksheet(1);
ws.SheetView.ZoomScale = 70;
wb.SaveAs("Bar.xlsx");
bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("Bar.xlsx"); 
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);   
... //response creation
response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);  
...
```